# How to turn Squid from HTTPs to SOCKS Server

Tags: proxy, squid, socks, socks5

I have successfully setup a Squid server, and it works well in HTTPs. I been researchign how to enable SOCKS access to it. And I have read some of the documentaiton. And it specifies that you need to run certain exports

> export CFLAGS=" -Dbind=SOCKSbind "
> export CXXFLAGS=" -Dbind=SOCKSbind "
> export LDADD=" -lsocks "

But there is little tutorial on how to apply it. Does anyone have a more thorough guide on how to do this?

If I can get a guide on how to turn Squid from HTTPs to SOCKs that would be awesome!

Thank you!